# Dart check num is Double or Integer

Tags: flutter, dart

In `dart`, as I am a newbie using `extension`, I want to make a simple `extension` to check value is double.

```dart
extension numberExtension on num{
  bool get isInteger => (this % 1) == 0;
  bool get isDouble =>double.tryParse(this) != null;
}
```

here `isInteger` is correct, but for `isDouble` I get this error:

> The argument type 'num' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'String'

Problem is `this` in `isDouble` getter!?

Comment: `bool get isDouble => !isInteger;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming anything that is not an Integer is a Float or a Double;

Why not implement `isDecimal` instead, something like:

```dart
extension numberExtension on num {
  bool get isInteger => (this % 1) == 0;
  bool get isDecimal => (this % 1) != 0;
}
```

**OR**

```dart
extension numberExtension on num {
  bool get isInteger => this is int;
  bool get isDecimal => !(this is int);
}
```

> **Note** that we could directly use "`this is double`" above,
> but the "`!(this is int)`" check is simply more change-compatible,
> because it would even work if `Dart` ever adds some new `num` sub-type.

---

**Update;** looking into [docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/numbers) tells us that:

- If compiled into `JavaScript`, there is no real `int` type, **only doubles without decimal**.
- Dart does not seem to support 32-bit `float`, but has 64-bit `double` at least.
- `int` is always 64-bit (just like `double`), but bitwise and/or shift operators truncate it into 32-bit (losing data or percision).

[image: number-platform-specific]

Answer (score 1):

Replace
`double.tryParse(this) != null`
with
`this is double`

Answer (score 1):

Your original approach:

> ```dart
> extension numberExtension on num {
>   bool get isInteger => (this % 1) == 0;
>   bool get isDouble =>double.tryParse(this) != null;
> }
> ```

doesn't work because your extension is on `num`, so `this` is a `num`. [`double.tryParse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/double/tryParse.html) expects to parse a `String`.

Why don't you just check if the object is an `int` or `double` directly?

```dart
extension numberExtension on num {
  bool get isInteger => this is int;
  bool get isDouble => this is double;
}
```

Of course, the extension is not very useful since `x.isDouble` is not much more convenient to use than using `x is double` directly, and the latter has the benefit of allowing automatic type-promotion to occur.

(Also, for Dart for the web, where `int` and `double` types are both backed by JavaScript numbers, numbers can be reported as both `int` *and* `double`, but using heuristics like `% 1` and `double.tryParse` won't help with that.)